# чтение файлов в юникоде из приложения UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

UWP Windows 10
Пытаюсь считать строку из .txt в RichEditBox:

Вариант1:

```
var read = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
txt.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, read);
```

Вариант2:

```
var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
ulong size = stream.Size;
using (var inputStream = stream.GetInputStreamAt(0))
{
    using (var dataReader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(inputStream))
    {
        dataReader.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
        uint numBytesLoaded = await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)size);
        string text = dataReader.ReadString(numBytesLoaded);
        txt.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, text);
    }
}
```

получаю ошибку: "No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page"

Нашел такое решение:

```
IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
DataReader reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer);
byte[] fileContent = new byte[reader.UnconsumedBufferLength];
reader.ReadBytes(fileContent);
string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
txt.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, text);
```

Ошибок нету, но большая часть текста отображается знаками вопросов в ромбиках.

Как можно считать файл что бы текст нормально отображался даже при неподдерживаемых кодировках?

Comment: можете предоставить пример на onedrive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос решен, может кому будет полезно:

1) Я портировал Mozilla Universal Charset Detector на UWP (добавил в [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UDE.CSharp.UWP/))

```
ICharsetDetector cdet = new CharsetDetector();
cdet.Feed(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
cdet.DataEnd();
```

2) В том же Nuget есть библиотека [Portable.Text.Encoding](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Portable.Text.Encoding/)

```
if (cdet.Charset != null)
string text = Portable.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(cdet.Charset).GetString(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
```

Вот и все. Проверил на кодировках 1251, 1252 - все работает ))